# How to animate CSS Translate

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, jquery-transit

Is it possible to animate the CSS property translate via jquery?

```
$('.myButtons').animate({"transform":"translate(50px,100px)"})
```

and does it work in many browsers?

Demo not working: http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/xWCVf/

**UPDATE:**

My solutions:

1. Simple implementations - http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/R3EaJ/
2. Complex implementation and multi-browser - http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: I'll take a guess, and say it only works in webkit browsers, if at all!

Comment: I found this example: http://jsfiddle.net/qGEmy/7/ but I cant seem to get it to work with my example.

Comment: And here's how you do it -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xWCVf/2/)

Comment: You could also do that without translate, altering left and top positions... http://jsfiddle.net/xWCVf/4/

Comment: That one I know but thanks anyway. I really want and need to play with translate.

Comment: Use .css() instead of animate, and add a CSS transition. Read http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/ to help you.

Comment: Sure thanks, I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('div').css({"-webkit-transform":"translate(100px,100px)"});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xWCVf/5/

Comment: Just add a CSS transition to it.

Comment: @IgnácioR.Correia - Updated link

Comment: EASY :D ! Thanks. You solution and http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ are the way to go! Thanks to all.

Comment: A side note you don't need to use the vendor, jQuery 1.7+ add this correctly.

Comment: You should also edit to add that you need to add a CSS transition to it

Answer (score 9):

There are jQuery-plugins that help you achieve this like: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: Lets try it. All I wanted is to add one line of code to my site. It does not required an entire library.

Comment: @IgnácioR.Correia If you are looking for a cross-browser solution I think a plugin/library is the way to go. Besides with jQuery you are already using a library.

Comment: I am already playing with it. Very cool. Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There's an interesting way which this can be achieved by using jQuery `animate` method in a unique way, where you call the `animate` method on a javascript Object which describes the `from` value and then you pass as the first parameter another js object which describes the `to` value, and a `step` function which handles each step of the animation according to the values described earlier.

## Example - Animate transform `translateY`:

```js
var $elm = $('h1'); // element to be moved

function run( v ){
  // clone the array (before "animate()" modifies it), and reverse it
  var reversed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v)).reverse();
  
  $(v[0]).animate(v[1], {
      duration: 500,
      step: function(val) {
          $elm.css("transform", `translateY(${val}px)`); 
      },
      done: function(){
          run( reversed )
      }
  })
};

// "y" is arbitrary used as the key name 
run( [{y:0}, {y:80}] )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>jQuery animate <pre>transform:translateY()</pre></h1>
```

Answer (score 6):

According to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) you should have it with multiple prefixes.

```
$('div').css({
    "-webkit-transform":"translate(100px,100px)",
    "-ms-transform":"translate(100px,100px)",
    "transform":"translate(100px,100px)"
  });​
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8 you no longer need to specify vendor prefixes. http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Comment: The original poster asked about *animation* which this code does not do.

Answer (score 1):

I too was looking for a good way to do this, I found the best way was to set a transition on the "transform" property and then change the transform and then remove the transition.

I put it all together in a jQuery plugin

https://gist.github.com/dustinpoissant/8a4837c476e3939a5b3d1a2585e8d1b0

You would use the code like this:

```
$("#myElement").animateTransform("rotate(180deg)", 750, function(){
  console.log("animation completed after 750ms");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need set the keyframes animation in you CSS. And use the keyframe with jQuery:

```js
$('#myTest').css({"animation":"my-animation 2s infinite"});
```

```css
#myTest {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  0% {
    background: red;  
  }
  50% {
    background: blue;  
  }
  100% {
    background: green;  
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myTest"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the original question about animating `transform: translate()` specifically.