# How to get popup to expand vertically up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have the following fiddle to show what I have for a pop up already...

https://jsfiddle.net/05w8fpL5/6/

I am looking for my pop up to expand in a vertical fashion up and down upon page load. An example would be on Facebook. When you click the 'more' link that is next to birthdays.

Ie- it  will say:

John Smith and 5 more birthdays today

or something like that. If you click on that you will see the pop up display as a small rectangle and then expand to the whole thing and display the content.

How could I do that?

Right now I have my pop up displaying on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // On Load Show
    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow");

    // Set time Out 5 second
    setTimeout(function () { $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeOut("slow"); }, 5000);
});

$('.admin_popup').on('click', function () {
    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow");
});

$('.close_admin_popup').on('click', function () {
    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get what you're trying to do. First create a wrapper around the content. Hide both the content and the outside wrapper. You can achieve a stretching effect by increasing the padding of the top and bottom while at the same time, **set a negative `margin-top` that is equal to the `padding-top` that you set**. That way, you don't move the element while expanding it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dashboard_welcome_help">    
<a class="admin_popup" href="javascript:void(0)">Click Here</a>

<div class="admin_help_popup light_admin">  

    <a class="close_admin_popup" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="indexpopupTitleWrap">
        <div id="indexpopupTitle">Have Questions?</div>
      </div>
      <div id="contactMessageStatus"></div>
      <form id="admin_help_form" name="admin_help" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
        <div id="admin_help_form_wrap">
            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
            <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" class="inputbarmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
            <label for="contactButton">
                <input type="button" class="contactButton" value="Send Message" id="admin_submit">
            </label>
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="white_overlay"></div>

</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow",function(){
          $(".light_admin").animate({paddingBottom:'50px',paddingTop:'50px',marginTop:'-50px'},170);
     });
});

$('.admin_popup').on('click', function () {
    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow",function(){
        $(".light_admin").animate({paddingBottom:'50px',paddingTop:'50px',marginTop:'-50px'},170);
        });
     });

$('.close_admin_popup').on('click', function () {
    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeOut("slow",function(){
                $(".light_admin").animate({paddingBottom:'0px',paddingTop:'0px',marginTop:'0px'},170);
        });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05w8fpL5/26/)

Take a note as to the `marginTop` values. If you change the `paddingTop`, you have to make the `marginTop` the negative of the value that you change to.

Comment: That's somewhat like I want, but I want it to stretch up and down, but first appear smaller, then stretch.

Comment: Well which components do you want shown when it is smaller? Just `Click Here`?

Comment: I really don't want to show anything in the pop up until it reached its full size.

Comment: I changed it so that it doesn't show until the outer box is stretched. Just use a callback function after opening the box. You can modify the "blind" effect to any jquery effect.

Comment: How can I modify it so that it stretches both ways?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to scale it from the center? Or do you want to stretch it down, then stretch it right?

Comment: Yes I want it to scale from the center and then stretch vertically in terms of up and down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88750/discussion-between-a-sharma-and-becky).

Comment: @Becky note that I updated the fiddle one last time. There was an issue with the effect not working when you clicked `Close`. I fixed that.

Comment: Thanks. One last question when you can. How can I keep the close button in the corner?

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012105/how-to-animate-css-translate

Add a class that translatesY your close button in the call back of the fadeIn