# TranslateX using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

TranslateX is not working for me in JQuery. I would like to use `.animate()` method instead of `.css()`.

*JavaScript*

```
$(".test").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({'transform': 'translateX(100%);'}, 1000);
});
```

*CSS*

```
.test {
  background-color: #f9333c;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

Comment: which browser do you test this? Is it possible that you are testing this in a non webkit browser? try also to use this: `-webkit-transform`

Comment: @Rotan075 `transform` hasn't required browser prefixes for around 4 years.

Comment: @Turnip oh never thought about that. I always used it just to be sure. Thanks everyday we learn something new isn't it ;)

Comment: jquery animate method not support transform so you need to use css method

Comment: @Turnip it needs vendor prefix for mobile https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fe6xx73/16/) using `animate`. I've added some code comments to walk you through what's going on.

HTML:

```
<h1 class="test">test</h1>
```

JavaScript:

```
//Get the element you want to animate
var testElement = $('.test');

function run(v){
  //Reverse the array
  var reversed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v)).reverse();

  $(v[0]).animate(v[1], {
      //The speed the element moves - lower is faster
      duration: 500,
      step: function(val) {
          //Adding the transform to your element
          testElement.css("transform", `translateX(${val}px)`); 
      },
      done: function(){
          //Re-running the function but in reverse with the reverse we did above
          run(reversed)
      }
  })
};

//Calling our function and passing in the parameters
run([{y:0}, {y:100}])
```

You'll need to play around with the values you pass into `run()`.

There is a [similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45857033/4826740) that show's how this is done with `translateY`, however I found the code a bit hard to grasp at first glance so I've dissected it a bit and made it work for your scenario with `translateX`.

Comment: I've found an easier version of what you've suggested, so still thank you!